# dropbox core api in android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox core API I have successfully written the code, but when I am trying to run app an alertbox appear and show this error"the app you were using submitted a bad request" I really don't know what to do I tried to search this error but could not find any this is my code please tell me what is wrong with my code???

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
final static private String APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxx";
final static private String APP_SECURIT = "xxxxxxxx\n";
private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "-xxxxxxxxxx-";
private static final Session.AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = Session.AccessType.DROPBOX;
public DropboxAPI dropboxAPI;
Button login_btn, uploadfile_btn;
Boolean isuserislogin;
private final static String DROPBOX_FILE_DIRECTORY = "/DropboxDemo/";
private final static String DROPBOX_NAME = "dropbox_prefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (isuserislogin) {
                dropboxAPI.getSession().unlink();
                loggedIn(false);
            } else {
                ((AndroidAuthSession) dropboxAPI.getSession()).startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);
            }


        }
    });
    uploadfile_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    uploadfile_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile(dropboxAPI, DROPBOX_FILE_DIRECTORY, MainActivity.this);
            uploadFile.execute();
        }
    });
    loggedIn(false);

    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECURIT);
    AndroidAuthSession session;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
    String key = sharedPreferences.getString(APP_KEY, null);
    String securit = sharedPreferences.getString(APP_SECURIT, null);
    if (key != null && securit != null) {
        AccessTokenPair tokenPair = new AccessTokenPair(key, securit);
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE, tokenPair);
    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);
    }


    dropboxAPI = new DropboxAPI(session);
}

private void loggedIn(boolean userislogin) {
    isuserislogin = userislogin;
    uploadfile_btn.setEnabled(userislogin);
    login_btn.setText(userislogin ? "logout" : "log in");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AndroidAuthSession session = (AndroidAuthSession) dropboxAPI.getSession();
    if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            session.finishAuthentication();
            TokenPair tokenPair = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(APP_KEY,tokenPair.key);
            editor.putString(APP_SECURIT,tokenPair.secret);
            editor.commit();
            loggedIn(true);


        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error in outh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}
this is my uploadfile class

```
public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
private DropboxAPI dropboxAPI;
private String path;
private Context context;

public UploadFile(DropboxAPI dropboxAPI, String path, Context context) {
    this.dropboxAPI = dropboxAPI;
    this.path = path;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    final File tempDropboxDirectory = context.getCacheDir();
    File tempFileUploader;
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try {
        tempFileUploader = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", tempDropboxDirectory);
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(tempFileUploader);
        fileWriter.write("hellow world");
        fileWriter.close();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFileUploader);
        dropboxAPI.putFile(path + "hellow_world.txt", fileInputStream,
                tempFileUploader.length(), null, null);
        tempFileUploader.delete();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ieo) {

    } catch (DropboxException de) {

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "file has uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you referring to using this Dropbox Android "Core SDK": https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android ? Per the warning at the top of the page, API v1 is deprecated, and no longer works. You should use the latest SDK here instead: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java

Comment: i am using https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java this sdk

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you're using and the full output then.

Comment: this is my code

Comment: i am unable to put my code can you give me your skype id so i can give you my code???

Comment: Based on the code you added, you are actually using the old version the SDK/API. Please update to the latest version as documented: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java (Currently: API v2 and Java SDK v3.0.8).